# mvtnorm package in R

Tags: r

I have two normal r.v independent each other (so correlation =0): X(18, 5.7) and Y(12.72, 30.38)
I want to calculate Pr(X>10, Y<10). Of course, as they are independent, I can calculate the product of the marginal density and the result should be Pr=0.3106.
However, I'm starting to learn mvtnorm package in R and,according to this article https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/vignettes/MVT_Rnews.pdf, I wrote this:

```
library(mvtnorm)
m<-2
corr<-diag(2)
corr[2,1]<-0
pmvnorm(mean=c(18,12.72),corr,lower=c(10,-Inf), upper=c(+Inf,10))
```

and the result is: `0.003264096`

where is the error?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming your rv's given are N(mean, variance) ... 
`pnorm(10, mean=18, sd=sqrt(5.7), lower=F) * pnorm(10, mean=12.72, sd=sqrt(30.38), lower=T) ` and so you need to give the variance to `pmvnorm`; ... so ... `corr <- diag(2) ; diag(corr) <- c(5.7, 30.38) ; 
pmvnorm(mean=c(18,12.72), sigma=corr, lower=c(10,-Inf), upper=c(Inf,10))`

Comment: Thanks a lot!It works!In case the two r.v has a non zero correlation and covariance (ex. correlation=0.5 and cov.=6.577) where and how do I put this information?Many thanks again

Comment: Just replace sigma with the covariance matrix.. `matrix(c(5.7, 6.577, 6.577, 30.38), 2)` . Im not to sure how this works when passing the correlation matrix

Comment: @user20650 I'd do it but you have to re-write as an answer instead as a comment, otherwise I can't do it. I've tried to do as you indicate with cov=6.577: it results 0.3104586..but I've write the function on Matlab to verify and it turns out result 0.2463. Tomorrow I'll check if there is something wrong with the bivariate formula

Comment: Just did a quick simulation... Try `m <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=1e7, mu=c(18,12.72), Sigma=matrix(c(5.7, 6.577, 6.577, 30.38), 2)) ;
mean(m[,1] > 10 & m[,2] < 10)` . Gives around `0.310`